# IO and other shell commands when a program is not started by a terminal

Tags: shell, terminal, stdout, posix, stdin

I have several launchers on my desktop for various programs, and there is a "run in a terminal" setting for those launchers.

When I check that setting, the program runs from a terminal, and logs its output there. I suppose that it could read `stdin` from the terminal too.

However: what happens to IO when the program is not ran by a terminal? **Also, what happens when I execute system (shell) commands from a program like that?**

Is there a "background" shell that runs those programs? Or does every program get its shell through which it interfaces with the rest of the system?

Comment: I believe each output stream (STDOUT, STDERR) has a default location to go to if it hasn't been manually redirected by the user. I would imagine that if output was being generated but not user terminal was present to capture it, it would be redirected to `/dev/null`. I could be wrong though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a program is launched (by one of the `exec(3)` family of system calls), it inherits the environment (i.e., shell variables `export`ed) and the open files from the parent. What is done when launching a program is a `fork(2)`, the child sets up the environment and files, then `exec(3)`s the new program. When a shell does this, STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR are connected to the terminal. What any graphic launcher does is up to it, but is should connect them to `/dev/null` (where should keyboard input come from, and where should output go to?).

If a program launched like that in turn calls `exec(3)`, it is as explained above. `system(3)` is a bit more complex, as it spawns a shell to do command line parsing and so on, and that shell then `exec(3)`s the command. But the mechanics is the same: Files are inherited, as is the environment.